# VS Team Services - Security Report Extract Displaying Users In Role Per Project

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to run a report against the security setup in Team Services that would display all users grouped by roles and project?

Comment: Why the down vote? If i can make the question more relevant or informative, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not the report to display users/groups in Team Services. You can refer to this code below to retrieve necessary information.

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("XX", "XX");            
 string url = "https://XX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection";
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url), cred);
collection.EnsureAuthenticated();

           var structureService= collection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
            var teamprojects = structureService.ListAllProjects();
            TfsTeamService teamService = collection.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            IGroupSecurityService gss = collection.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
foreach (var tp in teamprojects)
            {
                var teamList = teamService.QueryTeams(tp.Uri);
                foreach (var currentTeam in teamList)
                {
                    Identity[] appGroups = gss.ListApplicationGroups(currentTeam.Project);
                    foreach (var g in appGroups)
                    {
                        Identity[] groupMembers = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, new string[] { g.Sid }, QueryMembership.Expanded);
                   }
                }
  }
```

On the other hand, there is the REST API about [security](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/security/overview) that may help you.